# Why are shows like Gundam and Dragon Ball not available on iTunes (or other services)?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, gundam

Will they ever be available? I see that at least Dragon Ball is on Amazon video streaming, but only in SD.

I own some of the blu-rays, but it would be nice to have them in digital format instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any question of "Why hasn't X happened?" tends to be tricky to answer, because there isn't really much information on it unless there were already plans to do something (it's like asking "Why hasn't my favourite manga/light novel/video game/ukiyo-e been turned into an anime?" - the answer is just that no-one's bothered doing it yet and there's no real way of knowing if anyone even tried).

That said, here are some reasons that are mostly speculative:

- The distribution rights are complicated, because of the way that international distribution rights work (which, if you were wondering, is "poorly") or because iTunes isn't a streaming service so the way licenses work is likely to be different to something like Crunchyroll.
- The distribution rights are currently tied up in other licenses (e.g. perhaps Crunchyroll or some other service has exclusive rights to online distribution).
- Apple are asking for too much money and the distributors don't think they will make a profit from it.
- The distributors really hate Apple.
- The distributors don't actually have the rights to release the shows on iTunes for some reason (see also the first point).
- The distributors don't know that iTunes does TV shows now (just covering all possible bases, however unlikely).
- The distributors are in talks with Apple to put the shows on iTunes, but for various reasons they're stuck in negotiations.

I'm sure there are more reasons, but hopefully those are enough to go on for now.